How to plot a cumulative sum based on a certain columns
Below is sample data from my dataframe. I am trying to plot the cumulative sales by date (X-axis is date that is sorted, Y-axis is cumulative sum of sales_USD). Each item code needs to have its own curve. How do I do this using pandas?



Date
ItemCode
Sales_USD




8/3/2023
A
339


3/27/2023
A
289


12/17/2022
E
516


8/9/2023
C
138


8/21/2022
D
598


8/25/2022
E
674


1/26/2023
C
140


3/12/2023
E
727


4/11/2023
E
166


10/31/2022
D
609


3/15/2023
C
463


9/6/2022
C
929


7/8/2023
D
262


7/1/2023
B
504


2/22/2023
B
345


10/26/2022
C
602


3/16/2023
B
730


9/4/2022
C
831


9/16/2022
D
502


11/21/2022
C
684


9/7/2022
C
704


7/30/2022
C
222


4/5/2023
D
800




provide your desired output in text table like input.

To get the cumulative sum use groupby with cumsum:
df['Cumulative_Sales'] = df.groupby('ItemCode')['Sales_USD'].cumsum()

Then you can plot each group:
for item_code, group in df.groupby('ItemCode'):
    plt.plot(group['Date'], group['Cumulative_Sales'], label=item_code)

So it will be:
df['Cumulative_Sales'] = df.groupby('ItemCode')['Sales_USD'].cumsum()
print(df)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
for item_code, group in df.groupby('ItemCode'):
    plt.plot(group['Date'], group['Cumulative_Sales'], label=item_code)

plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Cumulative Sales (USD)')
plt.title('Cumulative Sales by Date for Each Item Code')
plt.legend(title='ItemCode')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

Result:

